# How do I get navbar-collapse to work with animated hamburger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a navbar that is supposed to collapse into a hamburger icon on mobile. I got it all working and then I added additional styling and animation to the hamburger button and now the hamburger button is always visible. It works fine, but I need it to be invisible when it is in normal desktop view.

https://github.com/thedonquixotic/UXReboot2

Here's a link to the github page I'm hosting stuff on. The relevant file is indexcopy.html

I hope I've provided enough information. I've been troubleshooting this all day and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Unless I'm blind, there currently (now) is no link to the github page in your post.. Can you please check again?

Comment: Oops, here we go: https://github.com/thedonquixotic/UXReboot2

Comment: Where is the css file containing your active class?

Comment: @rssfrncs: I was looking at that too, it seems it is main.css -> https://github.com/thedonquixotic/UXReboot2/blob/master/CSS/main.css from line 205 to the end of the css file. Perhaps a simple media query can be literally enough?

Comment: Yeah i think a media query is a good shout!

Comment: Why was it working before, and what did I do to make it stop working then? I just realized it might be because I overrode the navbar-collapse button class with the btn-2, by setting btn-2 to !important (sloppy I know)

Comment: Hmmm... just double checked. The !important stuff is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really simple really. The cmn-toggle class was overriding the default media queries for navbar-toggle in bootstrap. So I just opened up my bootstrap file and added an !important to the media query for mobile=not visible setting. Fixed it right up!

Comment: If that was the answer, you should mark it as such. Click the checkmark just under the vote section